# Count & group records with column A and do a count on column B with where clause

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

I have a table called `arb_visits` which has columns `country` & `clicked`. I'm trying to create a query where I group the `visits` by `country` and also get the `count` where `clicked` is 1.

I have managed to create the queries alone, but I have an issue combining them.

I managed to get the countries and their count by:

```
SELECT country, count(*) as visits 
FROM arb_visits 
GROUP BY country 
ORDER BY visits DESC
```

Which gives the below output:

```
[
  {
    "country": "United States",
    "visits": 113,
    "id": null
  },
  {
    "country": "Canada",
    "visits": 85,
    "id": null
  },
  {
    "country": "Germany",
    "visits": 84,
    "id": null
  }
]
```

And the same with clicks:

```
SELECT country, COUNT(*) as clicks
FROM arb_visits
WHERE clicked == 1
GROUP BY country
ORDER BY clicks DESC"
```

Which gives the below output:

```
[
  {
    "country": "United States",
    "clicks": 59,
    "id": null
  },
  {
    "country": "Canada",
    "clicks": 44,
    "id": null
  },
  {
    "country": "Germany",
    "clicks": 43,
    "id": null
  }
]
```

How am I able to combine these 2 and get an output as:

```
[
  {
    "country": "United States",
    "visits": 113,
    "clicks": 59
  },
  {
    "country": "Canada",
    "visits": 85,
    "clicks": 44
  },
  {
    "country": "Germany",
    "visits": 84,
    "clicks": 43
  }
]
```

In production, I'm using PostgreSQL, and in development I'm using SQLite.

I have tried, but with no luck. I'm kind of new to SQL.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? I'd expect a syntax error for `WHERE clicked == 1`.

Comment: @jarlh I updated the question. In production I'm using `Postgresql` and in 'development' I'm using `sqlite`

Comment: Those two aren't really compatible. I'd go with Postgresql in development too.

Comment: You really shouldn't use a different DBMS in development than in production.

Comment: I'm with you. I have some issues setting up `postgres` on my mac :/. I'm using Ruby on rails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `count` with `filter`.

```sql
SELECT country, 
   count(*) as visits, 
   count(*) filter (where clicked = 1) as clicks 
FROM arb_visits 
GROUP BY country 
ORDER BY visits DESC;
```

If your DBMS does not support `filter` on aggregate functions then

```sql
SELECT country, 
   count(*) as visits, 
   sum(case when clicked = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as clicks 
FROM arb_visits 
GROUP BY country 
ORDER BY visits DESC;
```

Comment: Fairly sure SQLite doesn't support `filter`

Comment: Then the old-school second option is the one

Comment: @Stefanov.sm I appreciate you help a lot. When I did your answer I got `near from syntax error` and it seemed to be the extraneous comma on the `count(*) filter (where clicked = 1) as clicks,`so when I removed the comma, it worked fine

Comment: Sorry, it's mine copy/paste error. Fixed.